# How can I remove the leading quote?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I am using BULK INSERT to import a text file into a table.

The data imports OK but is quoted. for example

```
"1235","Bob Dylan","Dylan","Bob"
```

I have read a bit on this and have I created a format file using BCP that resolves the problem except the leading quote. ie:

```
"1235,Bob Dylan,Dylan,Bob
```

How can I remove the leading quote

Answer (score 3):

In the past I have used an XML format file with a dummy row of 1 character length. Maybe someone else has a more elegant solution but that worked for me.

Comment: +1 As described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file.aspx